# How does scrolling work on the Stack Overflow FAQ page?

Tags: support

I'm curious; how did you do that widget on the SO FAQ page, where the question sidebar scrolls up with the page until it reaches the window top, then stays put while the rest of the page continues to scroll?

Comment: This should be on stack overflow with the [tag:stackoverflow.com] tag

Answer (score 2):

This menu is warped with a div, starting with parameters `position:relative`. This div is positioned on the right place using the rest struct of the page.

Now a script runs and when the top of this div is getting out of the screen this div get the style `position:fixed;bottom:0px`. This now make it stay as you see, at the same fixed position.

You can call that floating menu, and I have found and use in the past relative to that style here : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/staticmenu.htm